# Xamarin.Forms HttpClient.PostAsync never returns on Android

Tags: c#, android, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms multi-platform app, which shall utilize a custom Asp.Net Core Web Api. I've written the code to make the calls to the API, but it fails on Android.
I am suspecting some kind of SSL issue... but we'll get to that in a second.

I am using `HttpClient` and `HttpClient.PostAsync` for the calls and on Android - and only on Android - it comes to an deadlock on the `PostAsync`.

I therefore created a minimum example and started from the beginning:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
return client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Is working fine, then I tried it with my domain, which contains a simple Asp.Net page, which also worked:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
return client.GetAsync("https://aircu.de").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Next step was to try and address my API:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync("https://api.aircu.de").Result;
return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This now fails on Android, the line `var response = client...` never returns. However it is working on iOS and (in a testing .net core console application) on windows, too. If i add a timeout to the client, the application of course will run into that timeout and throw an exception.
I've tried using `async Task<string>` and `var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.aircu.de").ConfigureAwait(false);`, didn't work either...

I cannot find the problem; I've tried adding a custom handler for the server certificates, which did not help. I added Accept for the client and MediaType for a string content I added; didn't work either.
I've changed the Android HttpClientImplementation to Standard, Legacy and Android; didn't change a thing.

What do I need to do, to make this request working on Android?

EDIT://
To make it crystal clear: There is no deadlock issue! When I use any other url, like my base-url https://aircu.de it's working fine. The function only does not return, when using the subdomain https://api.aircu.de

I also moved my demo code to a VM...

```
private HttpClient client = null;
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        client = DependencyService.Get<IHttpsClientFactory>().CreateClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void Click()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(requestTaskFn);
    }

    private async void requestTaskFn()
    {
        var result = await makeRequest();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Result", result, "OK"));
    }
    
    private async Task<string> makeRequest()
    {
        string responseJson = "";
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.aircu.de").ConfigureAwait(false);
            responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return responseJson;
    }
```

I also added an `AndroidClientHandler` in the `IHttpsClientFactory`:

```
var handler = new AndroidClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
        return new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: why not `var response = await client.GetAsync(...)` and then `var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` (of course after cheking response code ... ) ... there is stated multiple times that using `Task.Result` for running tasks may ends with deadlocks

Comment: because `var response = await client.GetAsync(...)` won't return...

Comment: because your other code is bad - prolly you never await

Comment: I agree with your analysis that it is a TLS issue.  TLS is sent before the HTTP Request is sent and if TLS does not work you will never send a Request and never get a response.  The certificate used for TLS has to be loaded on both client and server.  Also the OS has to support the encryption mode that is in the certificate.  Older OS will not work with newer certificates.  See "View Log Entries" at following link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_https_problems_with_cfnetwork_diagnostic_logging?force_isolation=true

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, but that's bs. Then it would not work on windows and iOS. + i have tried that...

Comment: @jdweng Okay, what you say makes sense. But my code is working on iOS, the problem is on Android. Do you have a hint where to go here?

Comment: See following for Android : https://blog.securityevaluators.com/how-to-view-tls-traffic-in-androids-logs-6a42ca7a6e55

Comment: but you will never catch the exact excpetion if you are using tasks wrong ... take a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fZY0t9) (you may try it in LinqPad ... with `form.Click += OnClick` execution is stuck in `GetString` with `form.Click += OnClickAsync` it's working fine

Comment: also I've notice that I had problem with TLS on old windows machines ... and need to force them to using TLS 1.2 ... what is your setting in `Project Properties > Android Options > Advanced` HttpClient implementation?

Comment: @Selvin as mentioned, I've tried all implementations.

I've also tried using http only (with `[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]`) same problem, so it might not be a TLS issue

Comment: Some systems are configured that HTTP is automatically changed to HTTPS.  So trying HTTP will give same no response as HTTPS.

Comment: I know, but it's my server and it is not redirecting to HTTPS for the API. I can make http calls from postman, iOS or Windows. Same as with HTTPS calls.

Comment: IT's even working from the Android Simulator... I just noticed. Only my physical device is on strike

Comment: Okay, so I've got a bit closer to the issue @jdweng.
I've added ModernHttpClient to the project and skippt the certificate pinning for the api domain. Now I get a result from the function. The root of the issue somehow still has to be within the certificates

Comment: You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to get more info.  The sniffer will show version of TLS being used.  You can compare working and non working to make sure it is the same.  TLS the server sends a TLS certificate block with names of certificates that can be used.  The client then looks up names to see if the client has one of the certificates in stores.  You can see the names of the certificates in the sniffer and compare names on working and non working systems.  You may need to upgrade kernel on IOS to work with certificate if encryption method is not supported.

Comment: Check your Android kernel to make sure you have latest : https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/kernel/android-common?force_isolation=true

Comment: See folloiwng : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl?force_isolation=true#Updates%20to%20SSL

Comment: You may have issue if your certificate is SHA-1.  TLS 1.2 supports SHA-1 but not Android.  See Data Integrity table at following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security.  And read link on my previous posting.   This issue seems to have happened in 2017 and newer certificates so not use SHA1 any more.  They use SHA-256.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you very much, if've set up Fiddler and the Proxy to debug the communication. Once I had everything set up and the proxy enabled, the communication worked.
Then I disabled the proxy and the communication was still working. I took another phone and with that, it was also working. I still don't know what the problem yesterday was, but it's mysteriously solved.
Maybe the server certificate was too new?

Comment: I was wondering if this was a proxy issue. I suspect there is a cookie and code is going to stop working.  I would leave the proxy disabled.